# Is there an R fuction that arrange my data by row value?

Tags: r

i have a dataset got some modification.

```
data<-read.delim("data RNA Seq v2 expression median.txt",header=TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
data2<-distinct(data, Hugo_Symbol, .keep_all = TRUE)
rownames(data2) <- data2$Hugo_Symbol

data2<-data2[,-c(1:2)]
```

and it looks like..
[my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmLsn.png)

in this case, i want to array all columns(TCGA.A1,TCGA.A2,~~) by specific row values(such as UBE2Q2P2; in my dataset, target row is at row 4033).

How can I solve this? I'm so sorry for my terrible english skills and thanks for reading.

Comment: Please don't add images of your data. Consider using `dput(df)`.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I will keep that in mind. Thank you again!